# Leaflet setView Zoom unit

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

i was wondering how the conversion rate in km is at the zoom level, how many km are displayed at a zoom of 15? have not found anything regarding this or searched incorrectly

```
this.map=L.map('mapId' ,{ zoomControl: false, attributionControl:false }).setView([this.currentLat, this.currentLong], 15);
```

want to know what kind of km radius will be displayed on the map with a zoom of 15, and how much the increase or decrease of +1/-1 will be in km

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the leaflet documents:

> When we represent the world at zoom level zero, it’s 256 pixels wide
> and high. When we go into zoom level one, it doubles its width and
> height. At each zoom level, each tile is divided in four, and its size (length of the edge, given by the tileSize option) doubles, quadrupling the area. (in other words, the width and height of the world is 256·2zoomlevel pixels)

you can check it here : https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/